# Using Polyline to Raster tool in ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, line

Pretty basic question; In this Polyline to Raster tool, there is a field called "Value Field"

I am not sure what to put for this field. My polylines are ZM, so there is Z information for the line, I figured this tool would use that information to build the raster. How can I get the value field to you this z information??

Comment: Not so much. This isn't a 3d tool so individual segment elevations can't be exported only a single attribute of the line. Have a read of http://forums.esri.com/Thread.asp?c=93&f=995&t=277426 where someone is experiencing similar problems. The best you can hope for is to extract a string of points at approximate cell spacing with Z values then use point to raster.

Comment: Same Z value? Contours?

Comment: Yeh @FelixIP, contours would work, but only if the elevation is present as an attribute.

Comment: @MichaelMiles-Stimson, rather easy to populate new field with

Comment: These lines do not have same Z values. Essentially I walked a stream from top to bottom, so Z value is decreasing (rather constantly, as water must flow down hill:)  ). So I think contours are out.

Comment: Really, I just want a few values off each line. I have a set of points (about 5) that I have snapped to the polyline. I just need to extract the z value that these points are on top of. I know I can use extract value with points if I had a raster, which is why I thought I could maybe turn the polyline into a raster...

Comment: So this is more a vector situation, all you want is the Z value of the line at each point, is that correct?

Comment: @MichaelMiles-Stimson, that is correct. I just need to Z value of the line at each point. My data is in vector form. I just thought going to raster would be the best route which enables me to use Extract Value with Points tool. I am not aware of how to go about this any other way. Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the Z values of the watercourses at your sample points without raster:

1. Using the tool [Split line at Points](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00170000003w000000) you can break the lines (to
   an output feature class), if you have Z values the value at the
   point of intersection is interpolated. Use a small tolerance or the
   lines will not be broken, for example if your projection is metres a
   value of 2.5 cm would be fine.. it just depends on how well your
   points are snapped.
2. Convert the split lines to points using [Feature Vertices to
   Points](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00170000003p000000) (advanced license required) with the BOTH_ENDS option as
   we're only going to be interested in the ends.
3. [Add XY](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001700000032000000) coordinates to the end points so the values are
   tabulated. As the input points have Z values a Z field will be added
   and populated with the Z values of the end points.
4. With [Near](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00080000001q000000) (advanced license required) or [Spatial Join](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00080000000q000000)
   correlate the sample points with the endpoints (use a small
   tolerance).
5. [Attribute join](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//005s0000002n000000) your sample points to your near/spatial join
   table to find the Z value at each sample point.

If you do want a raster then create a [terrain](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//005v00000002000000), add your watercourse lines to it, build and then [export to raster](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00q90000002t000000) - 3d Analyst license required.

Comment: THis sounds like a great option. I question, my lines are already split into segments, which was an artifact of the data collection process. Can I somehow merge these segments into a single line before I use your workflow of splitting the lines at my desired point intersections?

Comment: Well, I have figured out I do not need to dissolve my line work, just snapping will work fine. I do have Z values when I use the Vertice to Point and add XY. But For some reason when I do the Spatial join, it creates a new point feature class with all the columns, but for some reason it will not fill out the xyz or m columns....

Comment: I'd go with near. It will add the NEAR_FID of the point that's closest to it onto the existing feature class. Spatial Join creates an output feature class. Also it would be best if you do this in a geodatabase - that way OBJECTIDs are static (stay the same... forever!). Ensure that both feature classes (line and point) for the split line at points tool are 3d and that your environment "has Z" is set to true. When you use the Add XY tool the Z values will be populated if they exist, if you're not getting a Z then something's happened to 2d the feature class (drop the Z).

Comment: Yep, I had ended up trying both and the near worked better.THank you so much for the help!!!